# When to pass self as a reference for methods?

Tags: rust

I understand the ownership differences that come with passing by value vs passing by reference, but I'm struggling with this when passing around `self`. When do I want `self` to not be a reference?

```
struct Test {}

impl Test {
    fn my_method(&self) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think too much. If we **ignore subtyping polymorphism**, we can tread all the object-oriented style "method invocation" as a "function invocation", by converting `a.b(c)` into `b(a, c)` inside your brain.

So, since you have

```
struct Test { }
impl Test { fn my_method(&self) { } }
```

`my_method` is simply a function that takes one argument, and when you invoke it like `testInstance.my_method()`, it's actually `my_method(testInstance)`, and `testInstance` is passed as `self`.

So **it's all the same with other functions.**
Think about when do you want a simple function parameter not to be a reference, and that's the question to your answer.

### Example

for `std::vec::Vec`:

```
fn into_boxed_slice(self) -> Box<[T]>
```

Comment: The `std::op` traits aren't a particularly good example of using move semantics (`self`) over references (`&self`) since most (if not all) types implementing them derive `Copy` and use copy semantics over move semantics. A better example would be an `into` conversion like [`Vec::into_boxed_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice). For your `Point` structure, you could use a `Point` to tuple conversion like `fn into_tuple(self) -> (i32, i32) { (self.x, self.y) }`

Comment: @EvilTak I disagree about your dismissal of `std::ops::*`. Taking by value allows types to reuse existing memory. For example, `String` and `Vec` both implement `Add`.